# Error when testing with JUnit using assertArrayEquals

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4

When testing this bit of code:

```
public static int maxRowAbsSum(int[][] array) {
    int[][] maxRowValue = {

                            {3, -1,  4,  0},
                            {5,  9, -2,  6},
                            {5,  3,  7, -8}

                       };
    int maxRow = 0;
    int indexofMaxRow = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < maxRowValue.length; row++) {
        int totalOfRow = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < maxRowValue[row].length; column++){
             if (maxRowValue[row][column] > 0) {
                 totalOfRow += maxRowValue[row][column];
             } else {
                 totalOfRow -= maxRowValue[row][column];
             }
         }
         if (totalOfRow > maxRow) {
             maxRow = totalOfRow;
             indexofMaxRow = row;
         }
    }
    System.out.println("Row " + indexofMaxRow + " has the sum of " + maxRow);
    return indexofMaxRow;
    }
```

using this JUnit code:

```
@Test
public void maxRowAbsSum() {

    int [] i = new int [] {};
    assertArrayEquals(i, Exercise2.maxRowAbsSum(numArray));
}
```

This underlines assertArrayEquals in red saying:

> The method assertArrayEquals(int[], int[]) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int)

Am I writing this the wrong way? How do I test this with JUnit so it has no errors or faliures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my code but still used Karol's example:

Instead of `return indexOfMaxRow` which just returned the index of the row that had the max value, I changed this to `return maxRow` this returned 23 instead of the 2 that JUnit was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

i is an int array while Exercise2.maxRowAbsSum(numArray) returns int.
Comparing them isn't possible and hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare an array of `int` (`int[]`) with a single `int` returned from `maxRowAbsSum()` method. That's not going to work, it's comparing apples to oranges and JUnit guards you against this with it's method signatures.

You should write your test to match the `maxRowAbsSum()` method return type e.g.:

```
@Test
public void shouldCalculateMaxRowAbsSum() {
  int expected = 3; // example value, change to match your test scenario
  assertEquals(expected, Exercise2.maxRowAbsSum(numArray));
}
```

Comment: What failed and what's the error message? The value `3` is an example, tweak it to match your test scenario.

Comment: I changed that to 23 the first time and its supposed to be 23. It outputs the maximum absolute value total out of all rows. When tested with JUnit it says the expected is '2' instead of '23'. 
The program outputs 23 soI dont see why its expecting 2.